# SMTP Mail Error on both server and localhost

Tags: php, email, smtp

I have an email account with zoho.com that is configured and running. On GoDaddy, I am hosting my site and have configured my mail such that any mail sent via the website is received at zoho mail. This setup worked fine till last week. Now I am getting errors and I have no idea what triggers them.

I get the following error on GoDaddy server when I try to send a mail to any account:

> SMTP -> ERROR: Failed to connect to server: Connection refused (111)
>   SMTP Error: Could not connect to SMTP host.

AND the following error on localhost for the same script:

> SMTP -> ERROR: Failed to connect to server: A connection attempt
>   failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a
>   period of time, or established connection failed because connected
>   host has failed to respond. (10060)

I have tried the following to correct the errors (on both localhost and GoDaddy) by:

- Changed port number to 25,465 and 587
- Changed smtp server from smtp.zoho.com to relay-hosting.secureserver.net
- Changed ssl to tls and vice versa
- Removed the SMTPSecure Parameter altogether
- Increased timeout variable to 1000
- Verified that the mail accounts exist and are up and running
- Verified that mail accounts have valid passwords and usernames.

A working demo can be found [here](http://subillion.com/trade/forget_password.php).I have echoed the errors out as well as the message to be sent just for the purpose of this question.

**Edit 1**  I commented out "$mail->Host="smtp.zoho.com" and got the following error:

> SMTP -> FROM SERVER: SMTP -> FROM SERVER: SMTP -> ERROR: EHLO not
>   accepted from server: SMTP -> FROM SERVER: SMTP -> ERROR: HELO not
>   accepted from server: SMTP -> ERROR: AUTH not accepted from server:
>   SMTP -> NOTICE: EOF caught while checking if connectedSMTP Error:
>   Could not authenticate.

Does this mean that GoDaddy is not authenticating the credentials?

**Edit 2:** My settings on zoho mail are:

> Incoming server: poppro.zoho.com, Port: 995, SSL (POP)
>   Incoming server: imappro.zoho.com, Port: 993, SSL  (IMAP) Outgoing
>   server: smtp.zoho.com, Port: 465, SSL  (POP and IMAP)

Comment: One assumes you have changed the password above.

Comment: No, the email and the password are as mentioned in the question. At my wits end :(

Comment: Add one more parameter in try block $mail->Mailer = 'smtp';

Comment: @RahulSingh No change! same error on godaddy server :(

Comment: @simrandhamija I thinks its not a problem of phpmailer.  It might be a problem of  misconfigured firewall on your GoDaddy. Contact GoDaddy they will easily fix this.

Comment: are you sure? i am getting a timeout error on localhost for the same script.

Comment: I just tested zoho with ssl on 465 phpmailer 5.2.16 with the smtpauth and smtpsecure properties.  Worked as expected.  Timed out under TLS.

Comment: Personally I wouldn't publicise your actual password, because you may end up rate limited or banned.

Comment: @progrock haha yes, i shouldn't be posting my password. However i quite needed a solution to the issue. Let me try the script with SSL and port number 465.

Comment: @progrock  I am getting 111 error (same as above) for both ssl and tls at ports 465 and 25 respectively. I suppose the issue does not arise from the script.

Comment: First change your password.  Then try and troubleshoot from your GoDaddy server - check if the ports are blocked.  Perhaps you are being firewalled by default or for good reason i.e. some comprimise of your app.  Can you not test your script locally?  It was working right?

Comment: If you comment out the host (zoho mx), you'll probably default to trying to send mail through the localhost, that is probably not what you desire.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try Using Following Code:

```
<?php
require_once('class.phpmailer.php');
//include("class.smtp.php"); // optional, gets called from within class.phpmailer.php if not already loaded

$mail = new PHPMailer(true); // the true param means it will throw exceptions on errors, which we need to catch

$mail->IsSMTP(); // telling the class to use SMTP

try {
    //SMTP needs accurate times, and the PHP time zone MUST be set
    //This should be done in your php.ini, but this is how to do it if you don't have access to that
    #require '../PHPMailerAutoload.php';

    //Create a new PHPMailer instance
    $mail = new PHPMailer;

    //Tell PHPMailer to use SMTP
    $mail->isSMTP();
    //Enable SMTP debugging
    // 0 = off (for production use)
    // 1 = client messages
    // 2 = client and server messages
    $mail->SMTPDebug = 3;

    //Ask for HTML-friendly debug output
    $mail->Debugoutput = 'html';

    //Set the hostname of the mail server
    $mail->Host = 'smtp.zoho.com';

    // use
    // $mail->Host = gethostbyname('smtp.zoho.com');
    // if your network does not support SMTP over IPv6

    //Set the SMTP port number - 587 for authenticated TLS, a.k.a. RFC4409 SMTP submission
    $mail->Port = 465;

    //Set the encryption system to use - ssl (deprecated) or tls
    //$mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';

    //Whether to use SMTP authentication
    $mail->SMTPAuth = true;

    //Username to use for SMTP authentication - use full email address for gmail
    $mail->Username = "care@subillion.com";

    //Password to use for SMTP authentication
    $mail->Password = "care@subillion";

    //Set who the message is to be sent from
    $mail->setFrom('care@subillion.com', 'care@subillion.com');

    //Set an alternative reply-to address
    #$mail->addReplyTo('replyto@example.com', 'First Last');

    //Set who the message is to be sent to
    $mail->AddAddress($touser, $username);

    $mail->Subject = $subject;
    $mail->AltBody = "To view the message, please use an HTML compatible email viewer!";
    $mail->MsgHTML($msg);
    echo $msg;
    //$mail->AddAttachment('img/logo-dark.png');      
    $mail->Send();

    // echo "Message Sent OK</p>\n";
} catch (Exception $e) {
    // echo $e->getMessage(); //Boring error messages from anything else!
}
?>
```

EDIT: if still not working then you must have proper configuration settings as below(as example):

```
Non-SSL Settings
(NOT Recommended)
Username:   jon@domain.com
Password:   Use the email account’s password.
Incoming Server:    mail.domain.com
IMAP Port: 143
POP3 Port: 110
Outgoing Server:    mail.domian.com
SMTP Port: 25
Authentication is required for IMAP, POP3, and SMTP.
```

Comment: thanks for the answer. Unfortunately I got the same error for your script on GoDaddy. I thought that it might be because of files not being called properly, so just to check whether the script could indeed communicate with the host, i commented out "$mail->Host". I got this instead:  SMTP -> FROM SERVER:
SMTP -> FROM SERVER:
SMTP -> ERROR: EHLO not accepted from server:
SMTP -> FROM SERVER:
SMTP -> ERROR: HELO not accepted from server:
SMTP -> ERROR: AUTH not accepted from server:
SMTP -> NOTICE: EOF caught while checking if connectedSMTP Error: Could not authenticate.

Comment: I think you have not proper EMAIL configuration settings. See my edited answer.

Comment: Where can i find these settings? Also, what are the SSL settings for the same?

Comment: Login to cpanel > go to Email Accounts > click on Email Account > Configure. Then you will find these details.

Comment: I can not change my POP/IMAP settings!

Comment: @simrandhamija does your password is correct? let my try locally then you can change it.